# Finding the user`s city without core location

Tags: iphone, ios, location, core-location

In the app I`m developing, I just need to know the user`s city, I dont need the exact location. Can I use cell phone signal to know the city, or an aproximate?

Also, Every time I use the coreLocation framework, will the app ask the user`s permission to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Location will use the Phone Signal for you, if you'll tell it to get not precise enougth location.

Just set `desiredAccuracy` for ten kilometers, and it won't use GPS.

Comment: But will it ask the user for permission to do so? I would like to get the user`s city without his interaction if possible.

Comment: No way - you want to know too much without asking the permission. But it will ask the user only once - that's OK with he UX.

Comment: Thanks, guess I`ll need to do it this way.